# Migrate data from snowflake to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we are using snowflake data warehouse in my project, we would like to replace snowflake with Elasticsearch as part of project enhancement POC,
i don't found any solutions for moving data from snowflake to Elasticsearch.
can anyone help me to resolve the above concerns.
please share sufficient information, steps etc.
Thanks in advance

don't found any clues on data migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it into 2 steps:

- export data from Elastic to AWS S3 bucket
- load data from AWS S3 bucket to snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the migration at schema level. Moreover if you specify the question with the issues. It will be helpful to answer and guide you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COPY command to export data from Snowflake to a file that can then be loaded to another system. However I am curious to know why you are trying to replace Snowflake with Elasticsearch, as these are 2 different technologies, serving very different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your data from Snowflake S3 copy command.
Export in multiparts so your s3 bucket has small files.
Then you can hook a lambda on S3 PUT Object. So on each file upload a lambda will trigger.
You can write code in your Lambda to make rest calls to Elasticsearch.